# Whats is benefits or difrrencess between Viewpager vs ViewPager2

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments

its worth to upgrade to viewpager2? I see as Viewpager is simple to implement

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Definitely, It is worth upgrading to ViewPager2

1. ViewPager2 will **reuse (recycle) Views** like RecyclerView if provided a regular RecyclerView.Adapter or a subclass (e.g. ListAdapter).
2. ViewPager2 also provides data-set change animations, e.g. if **DiffUtil** is used to notify the adapter about changes.
3. Viewpager2 has support for **Vertical orientation**.

Read more at: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration

Answer (score 1):

`Viewpager2` is advanced version of `Viewpager` with variety of new features. Viewpager2's ability to efficiently handle memory usage and smooth custom transitions makes it easier choice over Viewpager.

**Features of Viewpager2**

- Uses `RecyclerView` (View will be recycled thus using low memory)(*most important feature*)
- `RTL` (right-to-left) layout support
- `Vertical` orientation support
- Support multiple page transformers by combining it using `CompositePageTransformer`
- Has `dataset-change` animations
- Provide `DiffUtil` support
- `notifyDataSetChanged` works
- Easier to understand and implement

**Changes in Viewpager2**

```
 PagerAdapter is now RecyclerView.Adapter

 FragmentStatePagerAdapter is now FragmentStateAdapter

 addPageChangeListener is now `registerOnPageChangeCallback`
```

**ViewPager Vs ViewPager2**

1. In ViewPager, you can only use the horizontal swipe. No vertical swipe was present in ViewPager but in ViewPager2, there is a support for Vertical swipe also. So, you can use the horizontal as well as vertical swipe in ViewPager2.

   ```
   myViewPager2.orientation = ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL
   ```
2. You can add some items dynamically with the help of recycler view in ViewPage2 but in ViewPager, there was no support for the recycler view.
3. In ViewPager, there is nothing called Right-to-left layout support, you have to reverse the pages yourself but now you can use the ViewPager2 because it supports Right-to-left layout support.

   ```
   android:layoutDirection="rtl"
   ```